# kivy image not showing on apk

Tags: python, kivy

I just want to display image in kivy on button press its not showing then I convert it to apk

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
class m(App):
    def build(self):
        self.g=GridLayout(cols=1)
        self.b=Button(text="push")
        def push(btn):
            i=Image(source="/storage/emulated/0/im.png")
            self.g.clear_widgets()
            self.g.add_widget(i)
        self.b.bind(on_press=push)
        self.g.add_widget(self.b)
        return self.g
```

there is image in my phone "/storage/emulated/0/im.png" and I have storage permission add in buildozer.spec and enabled the app storage permission

> but then I add image directly without button its shows image

Answer (score -1):

Your posted code never adds the `Button` to the `GUI`. Try adding:

```
    self.g.add_widget(self.b)
```

to the `build()` method. Also, a `GridLayout` should have a `cols` or `rows` set. Try changing:

```
self.g=GridLayout()
```

to:

```
self.g=GridLayout(cols=1)
```

Comment: I know that I just showed example and its not about gridlayout wait i gonna edit